# FTP client for Chromebooks (Chrome OS)?

Tags: gratis, ftp, sftp, chrome-os

I'm in need of a free FTP client for my Chromebook which runs Chrome OS (slightly obvious but these machines can, in theory, run Linux too). Can anyone recommend a reliable client?

I've looked into [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) but it doesn't seem to be available on the Chrome OS platform yet.

Comment: Whatever Google says, the chromebook is most definitely NOT for everybody, developers at the top of that list

Comment: ChromeOS unlike Microsoft Windows and OS X is a browser only operating system as far as I know and would only be useful for people who only use computers to go on the internet.

Comment: Do you need to perform FTP uploads as well?

Answer (score 3):

Doesnt chrome in chromeos accept the FTP:// protocol in one of its tabs?
I dont use Chrome that often, but Firefox and IE do allow you to browse FTP sites with directory listing.

Here is a screenshot of chrome browsing an ftp site
[image: chrome directory browsing an ftp site]

This download specific however - I am unsure how to do FTP uploads using this method, but your question does not specify.

Comment: @henrywright - Ijust came across this piece of software which might help you out: http://www.sftpclient.co.uk/features-and-specs/.
I have no experience with this software.
It looks like it is for ChromeOS.

Answer (score 1):

## [SFTP File System](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sftp-file-system/gbheifiifcfekkamhepkeogobihicgmn?hl=en)

Essentially, this allows you to mount a folder on a remote system accessed via SFTP as a drive on your system.

[image: screen]

There are occasional hiccups when internet connection is spotty, but my experience has been largely positive. Transfers to and fro are quick and easy.

## [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)

You mentioned running Linux on your Chromebook in your question so chances are you're already familiar with this. This allows you to install a complete Linux distro of your choice as a `chroot` and run it simultaneously (not dual boot) with your normal Chrome OS system.

You then have access to a much wider range of FTP clients, including [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), [gFTP](http://gftp.seul.org/) and [LFTP](http://lftp.yar.ru/). If you use the `xiwi` target, you can actually run these as a normal window in your Chrome OS system without having to switch between the two.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I wish the SFTP service would work but nothing will get it to connect.  Such a shame because it should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've walked this road; native FTP is - although possible - very unattractive on Chrome OS. 
The best, in fact the only, solution that I've liked is Tonido. Look on the site, the server (in my case linux) is great, the user interface works very fine on the Chrome OS -as far as I was able to find it out, this was the only working (and nice GUI!) solution.